# I have an improved version of the code of this session, what should I do?

Tags: support, iterative-review

I published [this session](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/184872/webapp-substrate-script-for-wordpress-on-debian-nginx) which already has an answer but I have a significantly improved version of that code which it is important for me to share. Is it okay to publish another question?